# Is there any general syntax highlighter gem for some popular languages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, syntax-highlighting

I am wondering if there is any general syntax highlighter for some popular languages such as C, C++, PHP, Ruby and some others.

I found some syntax highlighter gem that works for Ruby, but it does not seem to support C, or C++.

I see StackOverflow has a good syntax highlighter for codes.

Does anyone know of gem that supports this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://coderay.rubychan.de/download/gem
- http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/
- http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

The second one infact does automatic language detection and works completely in the client side.

Comment: Wow, that would save so much server resources as well. Thanks for the info!!

Comment: ... and not only save resources, but also produce more semantic markup.